# Angular2 - trouble using ng2-idle EventTargetInterruptSource in component to create multiple instances

Tags: ng-idle

I have an Angular2 project that has 2 instances of a component (`DisplayAreaComponent`) on the screen. I would like each `DisplayAreaComponent` instance to have its own `Idle` instance (which is allowed according to the [README](https://github.com/HackedByChinese/ng2-idle#multiple-idle-instance-support)), so I am injecting `Idle` in the component constructor and then using `EventTargetInterruptSource` for the interrupt source. However, the interrupt source isn't responding to my mouse clicks, which makes me think I set something up incorrectly.

AppModule:

```
... 
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  FormsModule,
  HttpModule,
  NgIdleModule.forRoot()
],
...
```

DisplayAreaComponent constructor:

```
  constructor(
      private element: ElementRef,
      private idle: Idle
  )
  {
    // give the idle instance a unique name
    idle.setIdleName("display-area-" + this.displayId);

    // sets an idle timeout of 5 seconds, for testing purposes.
    idle.setIdle(5);

    // clears the timeout
    idle.setTimeout(0);

    // sets the interrupts for this component, in this case, things like clicks, scrolls, touches to the document
    idle.setInterrupts([new EventTargetInterruptSource(this.element.nativeElement, "mousedown touchstart")]);

    idle.onIdleStart.subscribe(() => this.idleStartHandler());
    idle.onIdleEnd.subscribe(() => this.idleEndHandler());
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are having

```
idle.watch()
```

function call missing.